# Why vanilla kernel image is so huge?

Tags: kernel

The following screenshot indicates that the vanilla kernel image is about as huge as 128MB. In comparison, the original Ubuntu kernel is only 16MB. Can someone explain this scenario?

```
user@inspiron:/boot$ ls -lh
total 195M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 899K Aug 14 18:42 abi-3.8.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 899K Aug 23 20:56 abi-3.8.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157K Sep 24 19:14 config-3.11.1+
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157K Sep 24 09:00 config-3.11.1+.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 152K Aug 14 18:42 config-3.8.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 152K Aug 23 20:56 config-3.8.0-30-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  12K Sep 24 19:15 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128M Sep 24 19:15 initrd.img-3.11.1+
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16M Sep 10 07:43 initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16M Sep 13 10:22 initrd.img-3.8.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173K Nov 27  2011 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 175K Nov 27  2011 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.1M Sep 24 19:14 System.map-3.11.1+
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.0M Sep 24 09:00 System.map-3.11.1+.old
-rw------- 1 root root 3.1M Aug 14 18:42 System.map-3.8.0-29-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.1M Aug 23 20:56 System.map-3.8.0-30-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.2M Sep 24 19:14 vmlinuz-3.11.1+
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.2M Sep 24 09:00 vmlinuz-3.11.1+.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.2M Sep 10 06:44 vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 5.2M Aug 23 20:56 vmlinuz-3.8.0-30-generic
```

Comment: offtopic? -> Unix & Linux, also it seems  you have multiple kernels in that folder - where did you get it from?

Comment: Maybe because this version of kernel is compiled with a lot of built-in module

Comment: The initrd isn't the kernel, try `cpio -vt <initrd.img-3.11.1+`